# PHP array modification by object reference behavior: is it guaranteed or random?

Tags: php, arrays, pointers, reference

Here's the code

```
class Foo {
   public $a;
}

$arr = [];

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->a = 1;

$arr[0] = $foo;
$arr[0]->a = 2;

echo $foo->a;
```

The result is 2 in my testing. However I am not sure whether this behavior is guaranteed or the behavior is random and/or will change based on the state of optimizer/version/memory usage/associative or not/...

Is it guaranteed?

Note: the reason I am having this question is the following code will output 1

```
$arr = [];
$foo = 1;
$arr[0] = $foo;
$arr[0] = 2;
echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

As those $foo and $arr are pointing to the same position at memory, so any changing from $arr will affect at $foo too.
in fact :
$arr[0] === $foo

if you want to clone a var from $foo you must test this:

```
$arr[0] = clone $foo;
```

so any modification in $arr wont affect at $foo and vice versa.